# Google App Script Add-on approved for publishing?

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on

Has anyone had an Add-on approved for [publishing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish)?

The submission is basically a Google Form post, but there is no indication of how long the process will take and no way to gauge a submissions progress.

From what I can see the number of available add-ons in the Sheet and Doc add-on stores seems to not be growing, which suggests there is a generic problem or bottleneck. Can anyone speculate?

Comment: Google have updated their publishing page with a warning - "Warning: After applying, it may take several weeks before we review your add-on and reply." so I am guessing they have a large backlog. Still not seen any more add-ons appearing in-store mind.

Comment: Nearly 3 weeks now. Still nothing from Google. Wonder how long "several" is...

Comment: Still nothing. I have tried to submit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just received notice and analysis of our add-on from Google. They have suggested a few changes but after these it ought to be good for publishing. So for anyone looking to publish an Add-on it appears it can be 2 months before you will receive any indication it is under review, but then publication could happen relatively swiftly.

Answer (score 1):

No need to speculate : as it is mentioned on the Add-on  anouncement page : "*Add-ons are currently in developer preview. Although the features necessary to build add-ons are available to everyone, only approved developers can publish to the store. Please apply when your add-on is ready to launch.*"

Meaning only approved developers have access for now... The apps that are available now were developed in the pre-release period by TC and selected users.

Maybe someone from inside the Google developper team will anounce an ETA, personally I don't know...

Comment: Yes, the form is an application to become an approved developer to publish a particular add-on. I am wondering if there are developers that have filled out this form and gone on to be approved, and how long it took. I haven't seen any evidence to suggest anyone has got through it so far.

Comment: for now all the developers were already part of a selected (private) group of user and they were directly asked to collaborate on this project before launch so they obviously didn't follow the "form procedure"... As I said, let's wait/hope for a Google team member  response for better information about the selection process and timing.