# Publish an add-on privately

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, chrome-web-store, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to publish a test add-on with the option `Private`, because there is nothing new in this add-on, and would not be accepted by Google if I published it with `Public`.

The add-on contains a sidebar, a custom menu and a custom function. It works well on its Google Sheet.

In Chrome Web Store, I have added 2 gmails to `Edit your tester accounts:` under `Your developer account`. I also created a google group with these 2 gmails.

By following [this thread](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish), I did `Publish ==> Deploy as Sheets web add-on...`, then uploaded different icon and images in Chrome Web Store, paid 5 dollars, left most of boxes blank, then published it with the option `Private` and chose the created google group.

However, when I open a new Google Sheet with either of these two mails, I cannot find the add-on in `Add-ons`. By `Add-ons ==> Get add-ons...`, I cannot find the add-on either.

So does anyone know where this add-on is supposed to appear? Is it because this add-on is under review by Google that it is not available yet.

I am quite surprised to see such a basic publishing is not unclear. Is it because few people publish an add-on with `Private`?

Comment: did you search your add-on under "Get add-ons"?

Comment: I just searched `Get add-ons`, the add-on I just published is not there.

Comment: As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715940/5995040) for you have to publish the add-on, and only publish it to a specific google group. This will let you use the add-on as long as you are part of the google group. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot does this add-on need to be approved by Google, if it is just for a google group?

Comment: watch this space, but for now private add-ons seem not to be caught up in the approval process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your web store dashboard, you should see the link to the add-on. Get the URL for this link and give the URL to the accounts you have created that should have permission. Those accounts need to install the add-on, and then should be able to use it.

I think you can also list your add-on as unlisted and not be required to go through the entire approval process. This makes it a little easier to share your add-ons with specific users.

Comment: 1) In the Chrome Web Store Dashboard, clicking on the TITLE of each add-on leads to its URL 2) give the URL to other people, if the add-on is unlisted or private for those people (better to make a specific google group), they will be able to click on `install` on the page opened by that URL, then they will see the add-on installed in any opened google sheet. 3) there is no review for unlisted or private add-on, though sometimes it takes 10-20 minutes to be available.

Comment: Just can't thank you enough for your useful comment @SoftTimur