# Test a Google Sheet add-on

Tags: testing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I have created an add-on in Script Editor with `Code.gs` and `Index.html`. I choose `Publish ==> Test as add-on...` and then selected another google sheet in the dialog box. Clicking on `Test` opens that google sheet, but I don't see any taskpane that should be made by `index.html`, `=myFunction()` does not work either in cells.

Does anyone know how to test this add-on?

**Edit 1:** `Code.gs`:

```
function myFunction() {
  return 100
}
```

`Index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    super add-on
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider joining the [Add-ons Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)  You have not provided enough information for anyone to answer your question.  You haven't provided any code.  If you don't know how to troubleshoot your code, read the [Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: I just added some code.

Comment: what do you mean by task pane? menu item?

Comment: The [task pane](http://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/numbers/intro/taskpane-defaultwindow.gif) is a pane on the right side of a workbook. The UI is coded by the html file.

Comment: You are using Google spreadhsheet and it is called [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)

Comment: I see... Then, I should `Publish ==> Test as add-on...` or `Publish ==> Deploy as Sheets web add-on...` (with `Private`) or `Publish ==> Deploy as web app...`? I am very confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely test the sidebar add-on, in other sheet. You need to use the below script. Also, make sure you select INSTALLATION CONFIG as **Installed & Enabled**.

```
function onOpen() {
   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') //your html page name
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Currently, custom functions are not working in test add-on mode. There is already an issue reported for this and Google as accepted it. [Check this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763437).

Comment: Thank you... Indeed, `Publish ==> Test as add-on...` works with the sidebar, but not custom functions. So to test sidebar + custom functions, should I `Publish ==> Deploy as Sheets web add-on...` (with `private` or `unlisted`?) or `Publish ==> Deploy as web app...`?

Comment: Deploy as Sheets web add-on as private and then check it. The latter (Deploy as web app) is for web based applications

Comment: This is what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888142/publish-a-custom-function), but I don't know how to load it in a new sheet. Via `Add-ons ==> Get add-ons...`  I cannot find the add-on I just published privately.

Comment: Did you publish to test account. Check this detailed [document](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#publishing-to-test-accounts) and [your dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)

Comment: Indeed, I did not `Edit your tester accounts` in the dashboard. I just edited it and added myself, unpublished the add-on and re-published it. But when I opened a google sheet (with my account), I still could not find the add-on. Where is the add-on supposed to appear?

Comment: I think its better to continue the discussion in the other question thread which you have created, since this question was about Test-Add on only