# How to grant read access to app script for testing deployment of google sheet addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, deployment, add-on

I have troubles to deploy for testing a google sheets addon(side bar).

This is what I managed to do successfully

1. created a new standard GCP project and changed the script GCP from  default to the new one by setting GCP id in the project details.
2. in the GCP console -> *OAuth consent screen* , I set all Oauth scopes, as I don't really understand what I need, and then added two test users. one is my the same google account owning the project, and another one I have.

Publishing status is **Testing**

3. In the script editor: deployed -> test deployments clicked install and done.

I'm not sure what to expect now..
[this link](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on) says testing users (I assume there are the ones I added on the *OAuth consent screen* needs read access.
My question:

1. How to grant read access, and to whom exactly?
2. After granting, what's next? how the granted users can get the addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays add-ons coded using Google Apps Scripts have two services to create user interfaces:

1. HTML Service: This service is available to *Google Workspace Editor add-ons*
2. Card Service: This service is available to *Google Workspace add-ons*

The [quoted link about testing](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on) refers to add-ons that use the *Card Service* but this add-on use the *HTML Service*<sup>note</sup>, so that instructions doesn't apply to it.

<sup>Note: The question mentions "google sheets addon (side bar)" (sic), so it's fair to assume this</sup>

To test **Google Workspace Editor add-ons** the add-on developer might:

1. Add the code to a bounded project and execute the add-on from the container spreadsheet. Depending on the purpose of the add-on the developer might share this spreadsheet or distribute copies of it to the testers.
2. Use the old Google Apps Script Editor to use "Run > Test as add-on". The developer might create spreadsheets to be used for testing and share the test links to the testers.
3. Publish the add-on for internal use. This requires a Google Workspace account for the publisher and the testers and they should belong to the same Google Workspace organization.
4. Publish the add-on for external use as unlisted. This requires to publish the OAuth consent screen for external use.
5. Design the add-on in such way that it can only be used by specific testers and publish it for external use as public.

Resources

- [Add-on types | Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/types)

Related (from older to newer)

- [Deploy and use Google Sheets add-on with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22664144/1595451)
- [Publish an add-on privately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45888142/1595451)
- [Test a Google Sheet add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45888364/1595451)
- [Publish Google Sheets addon privately (no-verification) with new G Suite Marketplace process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60813815/1595451)

Comment: you right, editor addon, wasn't aware of that. It is currently attached to specific worksheet, but eventually it will go on market place. Just to understand the process, will the testers install the addons from sheet addon menu?   when switching to legacy editor I can see the publish option, but what is the deploy menu on the new editor, is this also *card service* related? also, did I really need to change the GCP project?

Comment: most of the links you provided related to Chrome web store, which as I understand is another thing, or maybe the "old market". isnt it?

Comment: They are old post yes. The add-on listings (install page) used to belong to the Chrome Store, now they belong to the Google Workspace Marketplace, but the main points about testing add-ons like the limitations of using "Run > Test as add-on", using a bounded script instead of stand-alone scripts, etc. are still the same.

Comment: The Deploy button in the new editor allows you to create script versions / view the version number that is required by the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK.