# How can I "publish" an editor add-on to be used by just me?

Tags: google-apps-script, publishing, add-on

I'm involved in a standards development group where the meeting invitations are sent out, not as calendar invites, but as Word docs. I've written a script that allows me to take the Word doc uploaded to Google Drive, and run the script to create an entry on a Google calendar that I maintain.

At the moment, the script is unpublished, and to run it on the docs I use the "Test as Add-On" function from the script editor. That's a bit cumbersome because I have to go through the selection dialog to select the doc I want to run it on. Additionally, in the new scripts editor, it won't be possible to delete old tests and so my test dialog will end up getting filled up with every run of the script I've ever carried out.

It would be much better if I could have the script available to me, and me only, from the Extensions->Add-Ons menu when I open a doc. The script is not suitable for general publication: it works only on docs with the exact format of these meeting notices, so it should only be run by someone who knows what they're doing, and it accesses a calendar that I own, so I don't want to make it public. But I would like to be able to put it into some kind of "deployed" state so that, as I say, when I open any doc when I'm logged in as me, the script is just available directly from the Add-Ons menu.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is there an alternative approach possible to this general problem, of having a script that you want to run on multiple documents that you own without having to formally publish it?

Comment: If you have a paid Google Workspace account you can publish the add-on privately. If you are using standard consumer accounts (where an account's email address ends in @gmail.com) then your only recourse is to publish it publicly.

Answer (score 2):

One option to "test as add-on" without publishing the script as an editor add-on, is to use installable triggers instead of simple triggers. This triggers should be created by using code in order to avoid having to add any code to each spreadsheet.

If you are determined to take the publishing path you can set your add-on listing to be "unlisted", this means that the add-on will not appear on the Google Workspace Marketplace, people will need to know the installation URL to be able to install the add-on.

Other options:

If you have a Google Workspace account you could publish the add-on privately for your domain. If you don't have this account type or if this is "not good enough", you might make your Google Apps Script add-on publicly installable but limit its core features to be used only by you by making use of a dynamic custom menu. For details please checkout [Editor add-on authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle)

The dynamic custom menu might based on a setting depending on the user email address. To make this work, as the `Session.getActiveUser()` requires authorization to run, it can't be executed by simple triggers, but you might implement a workflow to save it or a flag, i.e. add an option to the custom menu to initialize the editor add-on.

Another option is to make the dynamic custom menu based on the spreadsheet structure and/or content.

References

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Enable and configure the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk)

Related

- [Google Apps Script: Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539911/1595451)
- [Publish an add-on privately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45888142/1595451)