# There is no API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, chrome-web-store, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to publish a spreadsheet web add-on but getting following error.

> There is no API Console project with the id specified in the
>   manifest's api_console_project_id field

[image]
Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error ?

Comment: Looks like you have not enabled proper APIs in Cloud Console. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#before_you_publish) link

Comment: I don't want to publish to market place. Why should I enable the marketplace SDK ?

Comment: Have you tried the options specified in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888142/publish-an-add-on-privately)? As well as this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664144/deploy-and-use-google-sheets-add-on-with-google-apps-script/22715940#22715940)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I think those links are not relevant. My problem is something else.

Comment: @HariDas :Are you publishing this domain for particular domain? Or is it    for everyone?

Comment: As per Google docs "Publishing an add-on for domain-wide install requires you to enable and configure the G Suite Marketplace SDK. " so even if you do not want to publish to MarketPlace you need to Enable this API and configure it.

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi It is for everyone. How enabling the SDK related to the error message api_console_project_id.

Comment: Is the Script Project on My Unit or on a Team Drive? Are you the owner of the project?

Answer (score 23):

Gosh... not sure why this was so hard.

If Google are reading this: it'd be more user-friendly to run the various API checks before the user selects to publish their add-on and/or provide a link to the correct documentation! Then fix that super cryptic error message.

Anyway, if you are stuck with this error, this is what you need to do. (Thanks Tanya Gupta for putting me on the right track).

**Step 1: Enable the GSuite Marketplace SDK**

Follow these steps:

1. From the Script Editor, open the *Resources* menu item then select *Cloud Platform Project*
2. Click the button *View API Console* (you can also click the link with your project ID)
3. Click the hamburger (navigation) icon on the top left and select "APIs & Services" then "Library"
4. Search for "GSuite Marketplace SDK". It's important you install the SDK (software development kit) not the API.
5. Click the ENABLE button
6. You should now be able to see an option for *Configuration* in the menu on the left.

[image: GSuite Marketplace SDK]

**Step 2: Configure the GSuite Marketplace SDK**

For configuration you will need to:

- select at least one *language* and enter an *application description* (for your add-on). The name should be pre-filled and match your script name.
- upload some *icons* of various sizes
- add a *Terms of Service URL* (I initially used a public Google Doc for my T&Cs but this would not pass the new [OAuth client requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) which require a verified domain. If you don't have a verified domain then users will see a security warning when installing your add-on. You - apparently - can use [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) but please don't quote me on that.)
- enable at least one *Add-on extension*

When you enable the Add-on extension, you will need to provide the following information:

- *Add-on Script Project Key* can be found from the Script Editor. Go to File > Project Properties and copy the value for *Project key (Deprecated)*
- *Add-on Script Version* is the version of your script. You can find the version in the Script Editor. Go to File > Manage Versions and select the latest version of your script.

Note: your add-on script version will be updated automatically when you publish new releases of your add-on.

Google documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-for-domains#before_you_publish

Comment: +1 for this, really helpful. What an absolute joke this is though. I see now reason why this has to even exist never mind being to cryptic and complicated

Comment: at step 4, what does this mean "It's important you install the SDK"

Comment: @Micklo_Nerd It means that you need to be sure to enable the API called "GSuite Marketplace SDK". There is an API (Apps Marketplace API) that also comes up in the search results which is not required to publish add-ons

Answer (score 7):

Just to build on [Dagmar's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136698/6563022)

Solve this issue in 8 steps with Pictures:

1. On Apps Script Menu Bar, go to **Resources > Cloud Platform project...**

[image: Resources > Cloud Platform project]

2. On Google Cloud Platform, go to the left navigation menu Select **APIs & Services > Library**

[image: PIs & Services > Library]

3. In the search bar that appears, type in "**GSuite Marketplace SDK**" Hit Search, once it appears click it.

[image: GSuite Marketplace SDK]

4. Click on "**ENABLE**"

[image: Enable GSuite Marketplace SDK]

5. Once you click Enable in step 4. the screen below should appear. Select "CONFIGURATION"

[image: CONFIGURATION]

6. Fill the document as you deem fit, but the most important part is shown below.
7. Scroll Down to **Editor Add-on extensions**, then select the Google App you're building your add-on for. It's the same process for Docs, Forms Sheets or Slides Add-ons

[image]

8. How to Get **Script Project Key**. Go back to your Apps Script Page.

Go to **File > Project properties**. Select the '**Info**' tab. Then copy the value of **Project key (Deprecated)** and paste into the "Script Project Key" field

[image: Script Project Key]

9. How to Get **Script Version**. Still on your Apps Script Page.

Go to **File > Manage versions...**.

Then copy the value of **Version** and paste into the "Script Version" field

[image: Script Version]

10. Click Save Changes and voila you're done. Do not forget to add the privacy policy URL and other required info, else **the changes will not be saved**

Comment: Building even more on these instructions I've created these instructions: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gG0_EClZC4ztKHDT2yn8v9NmUh_-sqYFe9vGg6Snxgg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've only found help for this on this page...what the hell kind of convoluted process is this without clear documentation??

Answer (score 3):

If you are publishing on Google Apps Marketplace, you need to not only enable the API, you also need to configure it by entering the needed settings.

1) First click on the enabled API as per image below:
[image]

2) Then click on configuration. 
[image]

3) Then fill out the values as per below:
[image]

4) Particularly important are (not shown here):

a) including correct oauth scopes (File->Project Prop->Scope from your script file)

b) Docs Add On Project Key (File->Project Properties->Info->Project key)

c) Docs Add On Script Version (from the developer console)

Now if you go back and publish you should no longer have the error

Comment: When I try configuring this I get error: "Project Key is not associated with current project or the script version doesn't exist." (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523275/publishing-google-script-addon-to-g-suite-marketplace-sdk?noredirect=1#comment95999274_54523275) ) one person suggested that I have to publish to Chrome Store first- seems like I am in chicken-or-egg sistuation.  Anyone know of a good tutorial (aka with lots of screenshots or video) that walk you through pubishing a Google Sheet Addon from scratch?

Comment: Apps Marketplace SDK is not GSuite Marketplace SDK (see my answer). Following these instructions I mistakenly enabled Apps Marketplace API which didn't have a Configuration tab and I was totally confused (it was late at night :P)