# How to share a Google spreadsheet with others that has Apps Script code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, deployment, file-sharing

I made a Google spreadsheet that uses some JavaScript in Apps Script to process the data into a flat format. I want to allow my partner and her coworkers to make their own copies of the spreadsheet to manage their classrooms. It helps them to save time and calculate grades.

How do I share this with them when these warnings pop up when they try to enable and run the JavaScript? Would I need to be verified in order to share this sheet or should I tell the coworkers to click "allow" despite the warning?

[image: Authorization to enable the js script]

[image: Google Unverified Alert]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to completely remove the authorization prompt but you could make it appear only one time for each user by publishing your script as an Editor add-on.

1. Create a Google Cloud standard project (GCSP) and add the OAuth consent screen.
2. Link the GCSP to the Google Apps Script project.
3. Deploy the script as an Editor Add-on.
4. On the GCSP add the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK, configure it and publish to the Google Workspace Marketplace.

Related

- [Deploy and use Google Sheets add-on with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22664144/1595451)
- [Is it possible to publish an Add-on for internal use without approval process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28990006/1595451)
- [Publish an add-on privately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45888142/1595451)

Reference

- [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)
- [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)
- [Publish an add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a routine security procedure. If they trust you, then there's no issue in them accepting it, it's just a warning if you don't know the coder

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization